# Fetch Realm objects that contain parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have a realm database filled with `Restaurant` objects that have a `url` parameter. I'd like to fetch the objects where the url contains what the user has typed in a `UITextField`.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"url CONTAINS '%@'", self.searchQuery];
RLMResults<Database *> *results = [Database objectsWithPredicate:pred];

if ([results count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"results count == 0");
    return nil;
}
```

Now, when I run this, I always get 0 results. Eventhough I have two example entries that have 'http://www.testingthis.com' as an url and the search query is 'testingthis'. Any ideas as to why I'm not getting results?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform your search query against the `Restaurant` class itself; not `Database`. Realm uses the class you specify to determine which table in which to apply the query.

As an aside, you can also inline `NSPredicate` queries with `+[RLMObject objectsWhere:]`, so it's not necessary to create a separate `NSPredicate` object (unless you've got a specific reason). :)

```
RLMResults *restaurants = [Restaurant objectsWhere:@"url CONTAINS '%@'", @"testingthis"];
```

If you're trying to query for `Restaurant` objects that aren't in the default Realm, then you can alternatively use `+[RLMObject objectsInRealm: where:]` to explicitly control which database you're querying.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on this. 'Database' is the name of the class that actually stores 'Restaurants'. (I know, legacy, I'm just updating something that's not mine.) Anyway, problem was that I wasn't setting the correct fileURL for Realm. Thanks for the help, though!